# Como usar o DropDownListFor em cascata no asp.net mvc

Tags: mvc

Eu Uso o Select2  para popular um dropdown e gostaria de apos escolher o item eu atualize outro dropdown ou um label fazendo uma busca.

ex:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IdEstado, Model.CarregarEstado.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Nome, Value = x.IdEstado.ToString() }), new { @class = "form-control select2_tipo" })
```

preciso que após selecionar o estado busque no banco qual país ele pertence.

Grato

Ulisses

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você terá que usar o javascript para quando você selecionar o Estado, o javascript/Ajax  passe para o controller o Estado via httpget, vá no banco e retorne variável com o país e preencha o campo com o nome do País desejado na sua View.

No Banco vc terá que cadastrar o Estado e o País correspondente.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.